# Objects completion in lists with the cashtag ($) symbol

Tags: r

Good morning everyone,

I have a very simple question.

```
foo <- list(bar=2)
```

As you all know, I can access the `bar` object with brackets or using the cashtag ($) symbol.

```
> foo$bar
[1] 2
> foo[["bar"]]
[1] 2
```

If I replace `bar` with `ba`, I will get the same result with the cashtag ($), but a different one with the brackets.

```
> foo$ba
[1] 2
> foo[["ba"]]
NULL
```

Is there a way to obtain the result `NULL` instead of `2` using the cashtag ($) in this situation?

Comment: I've never seen it called a cashtag before. Interesting.

Comment: @Dason [Here is an explanation](http://money.cnn.com/2012/07/31/technology/twitter-cashtag/index.htm)

Comment: No, $ does partial matching and you can't switch that off.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it's possible to get it to return NULL *unless* there is something else in the list that also partially matches the input.  So if there was an element in your list named bak then foo$ba would return null since the partial match wasn't unique.

```
> foo <- list(bar=2)
> foo$ba
[1] 2
> foo$bak <- NA
> foo$ba
NULL
```

You can also turn on an option to give a warning if/when a partial match happens.

```
> options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)
> foo <- list(bar = 2)
> foo$ba
[1] 2
Warning message:
In foo$ba : partial match of 'ba' to 'bar'
```

but as you can see it still returns the value from the partial match.  If you want it to return NULL in the case of a partial match then I just suggest using `[[` instead of `$` and in general it's probably just a better idea to use `[[` anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a way to return `NULL` even when there is no other partial match. There is nothing like `options(EnablePartialMatchDollar = TRUE/FALSE)`?

Comment: The way would be to use `[[`.  Is there a reason you can't use `[[`?

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way using @Dason help.

```
options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)

foo <- list(bar=2)
tryCatch(foo$b, warning=function(x){NULL})
```

It will be just fine for my needs.

Thank you for the hint!

Comment: I mean... sure that works I guess but I don't see how it's less work than changing it to `foo[[b]]`